# What is the set in Pesukei deZimra according to the Tur?

Tags: shacharis-morning-prayer, pesukei-dezimra

Particularly interested in the set of psalms on Shabbat and Yemei Toyvim.

Answer (score 4):

The essential weekday *pesukei dezimra* is described in [Tur OC 51](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.51.1?lang=bi) as follows:

1. A preceding blessing (*baruch she-amar*)
2. Psalms 145-150 (inclusive)
3. A concluding blessing (*yishtabach*).

He then adds that some places add Psalm 100, as well as *hodu lashem kir'u vishmo* (starting from Chronicles I 16:8) as well as other (unspecified) verses. Some communities add these additional verses before *baruch she-amar*, but in *ashkenaz* they add them after; Tur himself thinks it correct to add them after.

Before Psalm 145 the custom is to add the verse from Psalms 84:5, and after it Psalms 115:18. The custom is to repeat the final verse of Psalm 150, and in *sepharad* they repeat the final verse of every psalm.

Between the psalms and *yishtabach*, some are accustomed to recite Chronicles I 29:10-13, followed by Nehemiah 9:5 (the second half of that verse) until 9:11, and then the Song at the Sea (Exodus 15).

Shabbat *pesukei dezimra* is described in [Tur OC 281](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.281.1?lang=bi). He writes that on *shabbat* one adds psalms; in *ashkenaz* they recite the additional psalms after *baruch she-amar*, but in Toledo they add most of them before. He doesn't specify which psalms are added, apart from mentioning Psalm 92. He notes the custom in *ashkenaz* to omit Psalm 100 on *shabbat*, but writes that this is unnecessary. *Nishmat* is added between the Song at the Sea and *yishtabach*.

On the three pilgrimage festivals (*pesach*, *shavuot* and *sukkot*) *pesukei dezimra* is the same as on *shabbat*. (Tur OC 488, 494, 644)

On *rosh hashanah* it is also the same as on *shabbat*, although some add relevant psalms such as Psalm 17 and Psalm 81. (Tur OC 584)

Similarly, on *yom kippur*, *pesukei dezimra* is the same as on *shabbat*, but in *sepharad* they add many other relevant psalms. (Tur OC 620)